# MongoDB: How to find/remove two or more consecutive duplicates?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this device tracker that continuously updates its location to the DB.

To track and plot it's path, I want to remove the consecutive duplicates. Now the device may return to exact previous location so I don't want distinct location objects. Can I achieve this using only a query option/aggregation pipeline?

I'd be otherwise implementing this logic in my backend code. The records(including duplicates) will possibly be upwards of 10k.

Input (Sample):

```
[
  {
    lat: 15.550332,
    lng: 45.664231
  },
  {
    lat: 15.550332,
    lng: 45.664231
  },
  {
    lat: 15.550359,
    lng: 45.664222
  },
  {
    lat: 15.550319,
    lng: 45.664233
  },
  {
    lat: 15.550319,
    lng: 45.664233
  },
  {
    lat: 15.550332,
    lng: 45.664231
  }
]
```

Expected:

```
[
  {
    lat: 15.550332,
    lng: 45.664231
  },
  {
    lat: 15.550359,
    lng: 45.664222
  },
  {
    lat: 15.550319,
    lng: 45.664233
  },
  {
    lat: 15.550332,
    lng: 45.664231
  }
]
```

Comment: Is this input part of one specific document field or it's an array of documents?

Comment: It's part of a field but I've already been able to aggregate to above input sample.

Comment: So it's resolved? Can you post the answer to your own question? :) Would help others in the future.

Comment: Sorry, I think you misunderstood. I am able to filter TO the Input sample but still unable to remove the sequential duplicates. I'm still trying to figure out how to get the output solely using the aggregation pipeline. Will definitely post the answer for more suggestions. I think I may have to filter chunks of duplicates and then distinct on it.

Comment: I see. This looks kind of difficult thing to do on Mongo level. I would probably suggest to do that as a code since I think it would be easier for other developers (or even yourself) to read in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was able to do this by differentiating between the successive coords.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60596943/1531761) proved a lot helpful and I've used the same and modified the aggregation pipeline as below:

```
[
  {
    '$group': {
      '_id': 0, 
      'document': {
        '$push': '$$ROOT'
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$project': {
      'newLocation': {
        '$zip': {
          'inputs': [
            '$document', {
              '$concatArrays': [
                [
                  null
                ], '$document.location.lat'
              ]
            }, {
              '$concatArrays': [
                [
                  null
                ], '$document.location.lng'
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$newLocation'
    }
  }, {
    '$replaceWith': {
      '$mergeObjects': [
        {
          '$arrayElemAt': [
            '$newLocation', 0
          ]
        }, {
          'prevLat': {
            '$arrayElemAt': [
              '$newLocation', 1
            ]
          }
        }, {
          'prevLng': {
            '$arrayElemAt': [
              '$newLocation', 2
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }, {
    '$set': {
      'lat_difference': {
        '$subtract': [
          '$location.lat', '$prevLat'
        ]
      }, 
      'lng_difference': {
        '$subtract': [
          '$location.lng', '$prevLng'
        ]
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$match': {
      'lat_difference': {
        '$ne': 0
      }, 
      'lng_difference': {
        '$ne': 0
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Most of the pipeline is explained in detail in the other answer but to summarize, what it does is try to group all location objects in an array (some pre-filtering stages I've skipped above because it had nothing to do with the results here and only was projecting and matching some values).
I've added the grouping stage since my original JSON had other keys than the location object as well. Once grouped, it will update every object with it's predecessor's coords.

The last 2 stages are where I'm filtering the results.

The point is to calculate the difference between 2 successive coords(both lat and lng) and return those records that have a difference not equal to 0.

I tested it on about 1k records and so far it's been giving me the results I wanted but will need to do more.

Although, I'm still not sure if there's a better way but for now this will do. I'm open to suggestions.